# Django non-rel tastypie mongodb embeddedmodel decode

Tags: mongodb, tastypie, django-nonrel

I am trying to use django non-rel with tastypie and mongodb .I have a model which embed list of another model object  but when I query it EmbeddedModel comes like this

**Item: Item object**

I was trying to decode the same but unable to do it.

Here is the output:

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 1}, "objects": [{"postItem": "[<Item: Item object>, <Item: Item object>]", "title": "sdfdf"}]}
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField,EmbeddedModelField

class Item(models.Model):
    itemType=models.CharField(max_length=1,null=False)
    content=models.TextField()
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    postItem=ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Item'))
```

**api.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.bundle import Bundle
from django.db import models


class ScreenFeed(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset=Post.objects.all()
        resource_name='post'
        fields=["title","postItem"]
        include_resource_uri=False
```

**I have document like below in my mongodb database:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("563dc4b808fcd877fb057ba6"),
    "postItem" : [ 
        {
            "content" : "sdfdsf",
            "itemType" : "S"
        }, 
        {
            "content" : "fdsfdsfd",
            "itemType" : "T"
        }
    ],
    "title" : "sdfdf"
}
```

can anyone please suggest me how can I decode my embedded model data in the output JSON?Its been 3 days and I can not resolve it by myself so looking for some help.

Comment: What do you mean when you query it? What is the output when you call the api endpoint?

Comment: @dan-klasson instead of JSON serialised string.m getting a class object in the output

Comment: I take it the ListField is specific to mongodb. If you know how to convert the object to a list you can do so in the `dehydrate` method: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#id2

Comment: You might also want to check out https://github.com/wlanslovenija/django-tastypie-mongoengine

Comment: @dan-klasson mongoengine support has been discontinued since long back:(

Comment: @dan-klasson How can serialize Listfield in dehydrate method.Listfield comes from djangotoolbox.Can you Please kickstart how an I do it.Ill try to do remaining.

Comment: You don't serialize it, tastypie handles that. But you need to convert it to a list.

Comment: @dan-klasson ok ill try and I let You know about it

Comment: Here's an example how to implement it: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#dehydrate

You should be able to access the objects in `bundle.data['postItems']`

Comment: @dan-klasson hey I solved the problem  by using dehydrate method.Thanks alot and I am answering myself to help others in future

Answer (score 0):

Just for a future help.I am answering my own question.By using dehydrate method I solved it.

```
def dehydrate_postItem(self,bundle):
    results=list()
    for i in xrange(len(bundle.obj.postItem)):
        dictn={}
        dictn['itemType']=bundle.obj.postItem[i].itemType
        dictn['content']=bundle.obj.postItem[i].content
        results.append(dictn)
    return results
```

Now I am getting desired output:)

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 1}, "objects": [{"postItem": [{"content": "sdfdsf", "itemType": "S"}, {"content": "fdsfdsfd", "itemType": "T"}], "title": "sdfdf"}]}
```